# Camera with doorbell separately that is connected to the server?

Tags: mqtt, wifi, surveillance-cameras, door-sensor

So I wanted to set up a camera that surveys every few second and a doorbell with a sensor where I can see the person when someone rings it.

I wanted the camera and the doorbell are placed separately, so the camera can act as a surveillance camera also.

Can anyone suggest how should me set up this?

For the server, I was thinking wifi that connects to the camera and for the doorbell maybe mqtt that also connected to a monitor.

**Edit:**

I asked a friend to help me rephrase this. English is not my first language.

Basically I'm trying to make a surveillance camera that captures images of the person who triggers the doorbell.

Can anyone suggest on how I would go and start this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My idea is that the doorbell is connected and delivers the output to the MQTT server, triggers the camera as the camera is subscribed to the doorbell and takes the images and is sent to a monitor that has been set up in my house.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here. Please edit the question to add a LOT more detail

Comment: a camera and a push button switch are two separate devices, each requiring its own electrical connections .... why do you think that they are just one device?

Answer (score 2):

A doorbell camera will serve your needs. A good product is [Ring Doorbell Cam](https://ring.com/video-doorbell-pro)

Product Key Features

- Camera & Doorbell to Monitor Front Door
- 1920 x 1080 Video Resolution
- IR LEDs for Night Vision
- 160° Field of View
- 2-Way Audio & Noise Cancellation
- Motion Detection with Programmable Zones
- -5° to 120°F Operating Temp

Though you'll need a plan for the cloud storage.

Comment: This does not match the requirements of a separate camera and button